# IE8 : Dynamic Class Style Doesn't Apply

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

For example, I have following CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 150px;
}
#main.active {
    width: 250px;
}
```

If I will add or remove the class `active` using JS; the width of the element remains 150px in IE8. I tried adding `!important` but it doesn't even catch that className has been changed. Is there any workaround for this? These are the functions used:

```
tabScroller.onclick = function() {
    if(hasClass(this.parentNode, 'active')) removeClass(this.parentNode, 'active');
    else addClass(this.parentNode, 'active');
}

if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}

function hasClass(elem, theClass) {
    var className = elem.className;
    if(className.indexOf(theClass) < 0) return false;
    else return true;
}
function addClass(elem, theClass) {
    var className = elem.className;
    className += ' ' + theClass;
    elem.className = className.trim();

    return false;
}
function removeClass(elem, theClass) {
    var className = elem.className;
    className = className.replace(theClass, '');
    elem.className = className.trim();

    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Make a working demo with the issue, on JSBIN.

Comment: Seems to me that the code "if(className.indexOf(theClass) < 0) return false; else return true;" is not valid. perhaps the ploblem is here....

Comment: @GiacomoPaita It works on other browsers; the JS code

Comment: Ie8 does not have the same js parser of the other browsers, it is older. Check the js code in jslinter, to find syntax errors